# Admin user: Rails Environment variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, user-permissions

How can one use the rails environment variables within the application?

I am trying to use them to limit access to certain elements on the page. E.g. the users do not see the information an admin does; but the rest of the page is the same. Is there a best practice for such user privilege implementations?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you want to use environment variable for it.
If you want to limit access to certain elements on the page (or/and actions), you can use gems like cancancan (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or pundit (https://github.com/elabs/pundit) if auth rules are complex.
But if your rules are very simple, you can just do smth like:

```
if current_user.admin?
... admin stuff...
end
```

in the view.

Comment: My user information comes through Shibboleth (Single Sign On) and is passed to my application through environment variables. I need to check those to limit access

Comment: I think you should search/ask fro shibboleth-specific solutions. Do you use omniauth-shibboleth gem or smth like that.

Comment: I have the environment variables coming in from Shibboleth set-up, so I don't think that would help. I am trying to figure out if I can use environment variables to affect views in RoR

Answer (score 0):

You can use an environmental variable like this:

```
<%= ENV["Your_Username"] %>
```

This is an example of what would be in your database.yml. However, like the above user stated, it would be better to put the logic in your view rather than using an environmental variable.

Comment: I do wanna put the logic in the view but I am restricted to using either environment variables or the less secure HttpHeaders